# Why isn't a margin being applied with my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a div:

```
.divcom {
    background-color: lime;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 37.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
}
```

And i want it to have some space at the bottom before the page ends (Lets say 50%)

When I try to do `bottom: 50%` or `margin-bottom: 50%` it doesn't work (The color disappears).

I also tried putting `margin-bottom: 50%` into body but it didn't help.

Comment: Use `padding-bottom: 50%` on the body. But are you sure about 50%?

Comment: Your have applied position: absolute to your div. margin-bottom will not work in that case.

Comment: I already tried padding-bottom: 50% on the body.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for us brother

Comment: Here ya go: https://jsfiddle.net/yn2Lgbdc/

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely-positioned elements are outside of the normal document flow. They should be used sparingly, since they make a layout more complicated. Your element probably has a margin, but doesn't affect the other elements on the page because it's layered separately.

I'd also point out that `bottom` and `margin-bottom` are very different things, and that percentage margins can be troublesome (you don't always know what you're taking a percentage of).

For more specific advice, provide a more specific use case.

Comment: I have 2 divs. 1 is below the other. (CSS code: https://pastebin.com/raw/XMdh1tgi) i just want to have some space below the second one (50% of the screen just like i had with the first one) (just for it to look fancy and not weird)

Comment: A snippet of CSS is not a useful demonstration. Also, your comment doesn't change anything about my answer. If you want more help, provide more information (in your question).

Comment: I said, that i want the second div (the one from my question) to have some space between it and the end of the page because right now its just sitting on the complete bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `margin-bottom` to `auto` and setting `bottom` to 10px. I can't really tell what you're trying though because of `top` which is set to 100%

Comment: I meant `auto`, not `0`

Comment: I have 2 divs. 1 is below the other. (CSS code: pastebin.com/raw/XMdh1tgi) i just want to have some space below the second one (50% of the screen just like i had with the first one) (just for it to look fancy and not weird)